# C++ API for Google Finance

Tags: c++, google-finance, google-finance-api

Is there a C++ API for accessing stock quotes from Google finance?

Comment: Did you do a search before asking? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=google+finance+stock+quote shows that similar questions have been asked a few hundred times already. The answers may not be specific to C++, but the language makes little difference in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no C++ client library, if that is what you mean - just for [Java and Javascript](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/docs/2.0/developers_guide.html).

There are plenty of C++ libraries for HTTP and XML though, so you can certainly process the protocol directly if you wish.  I guess you could call the Java client library using JNI also.

Answer (score 2):

The best course of action would probably be to use Boost.Asio to fetch the URL of interest, and process it yourself.  Shouldn't be too hard.  I have some example code here:

// Burst.Asio.HTTP.Client Example 1
https://github.com/hank/life/blob/master/code/cpp/burst/examples/asio.http_client/asio.http.1.cpp

// Burst.Asio.HTTP.Client
https://github.com/hank/life/blob/master/code/cpp/burst/include/burst/asio/http/client.hpp